# MPI on Sun Grid Engine cluster

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, openmpi, mpich, sungridengine

I am running MPI applications on a cluster with Sun Grid Engine, using OpenMPI.

Has anyone ever experience MPI communications which hang while the applications are running?

For example: Process on rank 0 calls MPI_Send to process on rank 1, and process on rank 1 calls MPI_Recv from process on rank 0. The ranks are correct, the tags are correct, however the communication just does not happen therefore the application never terminates.

N.B. The applications work on my laptop and other machines so it is not a case that I have some IDs wrong... Also, these applications work on the cluster the first time, but when I submit the exact same job again the MPI communication hangs as explained above.

If anyone has experienced something similar, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
I have implemented a very simple example of one of the applications:

```
    #include <mpi.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define NUM_CELLS 5     //Total number of integers to sort

/* Initial process to create numbers and send to first cell */ 
void *start(void *data)
{
    int i, num;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    //Create array of random numbers and print
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_CELLS; i++) 
    {
        num = rand() % 100;
        printf("0 SEND\n");
        MPI_Send(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        printf("0 SENT\n");
  }
  return NULL;
}

/* Process for individual sort cell in sort pump */
void *sort_cell(void *data)
{   
    int *pos = (int *)data;

    int num=2, i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_CELLS; i++)
    {
        //Receive num
        printf("%d WAIT\n", *pos);           
        if(*pos == 1) 
              MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        else if(*pos == 2)
              MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        else if(*pos == 3)
              MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        else if(*pos == 4)
              MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 3, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        else if(*pos == 5)
              MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 4, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("%d RECV\n", *pos);

        //Keep larger number and send smaller number to next cell
        printf("%d SEND\n", *pos); 
        if(*pos == 1)
          MPI_Send(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
        else if(*pos == 2)
          MPI_Send(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 3, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        else if(*pos == 3) 
          MPI_Send(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 4, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
        else if(*pos == 4) 
          MPI_Send(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("%d SENT\n", *pos);
  } 
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    double elapsedTime;
    struct timeval t1, t2;

    //Start timer
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

  int my_rank, provided; 
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);  
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    //Stop timer
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

    elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      //sec to ms
    elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   //us to ms

    printf("Rank %d - Setup time: %f milliseconds\n", my_rank, elapsedTime);

    //Start timer
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    //Execute processes in parallel according to mapping
  if(my_rank == 0)
  {
    int num_threads = 1;

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, start, NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        (void) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); 
  }
  if(my_rank == 1)
  {
    int pos = 1;
    int num_threads = 2;

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, sort_cell, (void *) &pos);

    int pos1 = 5;
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, sort_cell, (void *) &pos1);

    for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        (void) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); 
  }

  if(my_rank == 2)
  {
    int pos = 2;
    int num_threads = 1;

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, sort_cell, (void *) &pos);

    for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        (void) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  if(my_rank == 3)
  {
    int pos = 3;
    int num_threads = 1;

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, sort_cell, (void *) &pos);

    for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        (void) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  if(my_rank == 4)
  {
    int pos = 4;
    int num_threads = 1;

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, sort_cell, (void *) &pos);

    for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        (void) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //Stop timer
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

    elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      //sec to ms
  elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   //us to ms

    printf("Rank %d - Execution time: %f milliseconds\n", my_rank, elapsedTime);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Depending on the order of the sort_cells on the ranks, it works and I cannot understand why..

The application is as follows: 
     Sort_cell -> Sort_cell -> Sort_cell -> Sort_cell -> Sort_cell -> Sort_cell
ranks:    0            1            2            3            4            1
(where each Sort_cell is a process run on the specified ranks respectively)

If these are run on ranks which are grouped, ie: 00111, 01233, 00112, etc it works.. but once i execute on a stray rank (like the above example) ie: 00110, 01221, 01231, etc the MPI communication hangs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply... I have implemented a very simple example of one of the applications here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xo2rizt7ebrk2rl/manual.c?dl=0

Depending on the order of the sort_cells on the ranks, it works and I cannot understand why:

Application is as follows:
Sort_cell -> Sort_cell -> Sort_cell -> Sort_Cell -> Sort_cell

If these are run on ranks which are grouped, ie: 00111, 01233, 00112, etc it works.. but once i execute on a stray rank, ie: 00110, 01221, 01231, etc the MPI communication hangs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok no problem I edited the question, thanks

Comment: You are not even checking the value returned by `MPI_Init_thread` in `provided`. Is it equal to `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`? If not, Open MPI was not built with support for multiple threads and hangs (or even crashes) are to be expected.

Comment: @HristoIliev Hi yes I checked it, it is set to MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE‌, sorry I didn't include it in the above code.